# How to make a ChainLink solidity oracle asynchronous call?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I need to introduce a uint in my Ethereum contract. I am testing  this code in Kovan in base to this example:   https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";

// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

contract ChainlinkExample is ChainlinkClient {
  
    uint256 public price;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    constructor() public {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e;
        jobId = "29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
    }

    function requestEthereumPrice() public returns (bytes32 requestId){
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
            req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD");//{"USD":1797.12}
            req.add("path", "USD");
            req.addInt("times", 100);
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }

    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _price) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId){
        price = _price;
    }

}
```

All works correctly, but "requestEthereumPrice()" function takes a few seconds to save the variable "price".

How could I call a request, wait the answer and continue with my next code claculations?

For example, how can I request the API price and make an operation and return the result in the same function call?

Comment: Please don't add another question to the same question in stackoverflow. Can you please create a new question titled "How to return a Chainlink API Call to another contract"?

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to place all your logic in the callback function, in this case `fulfill`.

For example, if you wanted to mint some token based on the return of an API call, you'd do something like:

```
function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _price) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId){
        price = _price;
        mint(price);
        // any other logic here
    }
```

Chainlink API Calls are asynchronous by nature, so you don't make an API call and get a response in the same block.

Comment: I need to call the "requestEthereumPrice()" function from other contract. How can I return the "price" to the parent contract?

Comment: You'd want the callback address to be the other contract. `buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);` swap out `address(this)` for whatever address you want it to return to.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I am trying but  I can't get it to work in a simple way. Could you guide me? Thanks. (Look the EDIT section)